# Adding Areas to a hybrid MVC-Webforms application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I am adding MVC support to a legacy ASP.NET Website project. I have added a separate class library for the `Controllers` and the `Views` are in the legacy app. It works great so far, but I'd like to take advantage of `Areas`. Since `Areas` encapsulate `Controllers`, `Views` and `Models`, if i add a new class project to host the `Areas` then would it work with the `Views` in this project?

Also, `Areas` need a `web.config` file and I assume I cant add a web.config to a class library Areas project.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the View files can be placed outside of the MVC3 project (it has to know where to find the files).

You can, however, specify a namespace for your Area routes that specifies where to search for your Controllers (so your controllers can remain in a separate project).

```
context.MapRoute("routename",
  "{controller}/{action}",
  new { controller="Home",action="Index"},
  null,
  new[] {"ControllerProject.NamespaceTo.Controllers"}
);
```

Comment: My question is regarding using areas in a hybrid MVC Webforms application.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be sure you reference the proper ProjectTypeGuids in your project file.

http://www.kevinrohrbaugh.com/blog/2009/7/17/demystifying-the-aspnet-mvc-project-type.html

Be sure you have added the proper references for MVC as well. When all is configured, visual studios should allow you to right click the project and add areas with the supporting structure.